# es6 import moment.js in angular angular.js Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Moment

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I found moment.js had supported ES6, but when I import it

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

I got an error like this:

```
angular.js?5638:68Uncaught  Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Moment
```

I had tried some different way to do:

```
import moment from 'moment/src/moment';
```

still does not work.

Comment: Are you using a module loader? E.g.: https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs

SystemJS is a universal module loader, which can also be used to load other module formats.

Comment: When using webpack you need to add in module.exports{entry:{"moment"}}

Comment: no,last I config it in webpack to be  global then it works. it can be import but may be a compatibility error .  I saw it did have a fix for es6.