# angular.js Uncaught Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Moment while working on angular-ui-calendar based calendar widget

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, angular-calendar

I've found this topic earlier [es6 import moment.js in angular angular.js Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Moment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40543331/es6-import-moment-js-in-angular-angular-js-error-ngareq-argument-fn-is-not), unfortunately, it wasn't solved.
So I decided to refresh this question and ask it again, this time by myself.

I'm importing moment.js from inside my app.js file, which is a source of my app's main module initialization:

```
...
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.js';
import moment from 'moment/moment.js';
import 'fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js';
import 'fullcalendar/dist/gcal.min.js';
import 'angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js';

const app = angular
  .module('app', [
    uiRouter,
    uiBootstrap,
    'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker',
    uiMask,
    cookies,
    ngTranslate,
    'ng-currency',
    moment,
    'ui.calendar',
    sanitize,
    uiSelect,
    uiNotification,
    'mm.acl',
    Common.name,
    Components.name
  ])
```

Above shown way of importing and dependency injection of moment.js lib, causes such error:

```
Uncaught Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Moment
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20Moment
```

Really don't know how to make it work.
Also, using webpack for app building process, but all new libraries and directives are imported into app's code directly, with ES6 `import` or `require` statements.
I'm not using webpack config for building and loading every single 3rd party module with webpack.
Don't have any clue how to import moment.js and make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`angular-moment`](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) instead of the native momentjs package.

Comment: Added:
`import 'jquery/dist/jquery.js';
import moment from 'moment';
import angularMoment from 'angular-moment';
import 'fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js';
import 'fullcalendar/dist/gcal.min.js';
import 'angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js';

const app = angular
  .module('app', [
    ...
    'ng-currency',
    angularMoment,
    'ui.calendar',
    ...`
but now theres another:
`ReferenceError: moment is not defined` and `TypeError: calendar.fullCalendar is not a function`, because I'm using for now demo from https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar to test this lib

Comment: `angular-moment` assumes moment is global, but you are assigning momentjs to an own object named `moment`. Try `import 'moment'` instead.

Comment: Ok, had to import both moment.js and then angular-moment. Now it works.

Comment: Also, angular-ui-calendar has some bug, which still causes `ReferenceError: moment is not defined`. What I did was to instead of `import 'moment';` type `window.moment = require('moment');` and now calendar module works.